# Perform array rotation using Linked lists

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

I was going through available solutions to an array rotation problem (specifically a left array rotation), given a number 'd' (the number of array rotations you need to perform).

I have not seen any solutions trying to achieve this using linked lists. Is it not possible to convert the array provided into a Linked List, start a for loop and for each iteration, remove the head and add it to the end, till 'd'. It can now be converted into an array again.

Is there a problem with this approach?

Comment: `list.add(list.remove(0));` and `list.add(0, list.remove(list.size() - 1));`

Comment: `java.util.LinkedList`? **Do not use it.** For `java.util.List` use `Collections.rotate`.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline, possible to link me to sources explaining why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/323889/4725 Here's Stuart Marks, Mr Streams, the other day: https://twitter.com/stuartmarks/status/1241522641707532289. And, Josh Bloch, the author of the class: https://twitter.com/joshbloch/status/583813919019573248